# Compare two arrays of objects and find out if the date from the first array is within the specified range in the second array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
let array1 = [
    {
        start_date: 2022-12-01,
        end_date: 2022-12-07,
        status: ready,
    },
    {
        start_date: 2022-12-04,
        end_date: 2022-12-10,
        status: ready,
    },
    
   {
        start_date: 2022-12-8,
        end_date: 2022-12-14,
        status: ready,
    },
    {
        start_date: 2022-12-11,
        end_date: 2022-12-17,
        status: ready,
    },
   {
        start_date: 2022-12-15,
        end_date: 2022-12-21,
        status: overlap,
    },

   {
        start_date: 2022-12-18,
        end_date: 2022-12-24,
        status: overlap,
    },

   {
        start_date: 2022-12-22,
        end_date: 2022-12-28,
        status: overlap,
    },
    {
        start_date: 2022-12-25,
        end_date: 2022-12-31,
        status: overlap,
    },
    
    {
        start_date: 2022-12-18,
        end_date: 2022-12-31,
        status: match,
    },

    
];




let array2 = [
    {
        start_date: 2022-12-18,
        end_date: 2022-12-31
    }
];
```

I have two array of objects and

1. would like to compare start date of array 1 against array 2 to see if array 1 start date is within the range of array 2 start date and end date

then also compare end date of array 1 against array 2 to see if array 1 end date is within the range of array 2 start date and end date

if both the condition above are met then validate if array 1 status is overlap.

eg: Dec 15-21 (array 1 - start date -end date ) Dec 18-31 (from array 2  start date -end date)

2. if array1 start date is outside the range of array 2 start and end date, then validate array 1 status is ready . and if array1 end date is outside the range of array 2 start and end date, then validate array 1 status is ready .

eg: Dec 01-07 (array 1 - start date -end date ) Dec 18-31 (from array 2  start date -end date)

3. and if array 1 start date matches array 2 start date and array 1 end date matches array 2 end date then validate array 1 status is match,

eg: Dec 18-31 (array 1 - start date -end date ) Dec 18-31 (from array 2  start date -end date)

Can you please advise how to achieve this using javascript.

can you please advise if something like this is possible or any better solution, if there is a way to validate the status is either overlap/ready/available within every block or make every block return the status instead of just boolean value - true/false

```js
let compareTwoArrayOfObjects = (
    array1,
    array2
) => {
    return (
        array2.every((element_2) =>
            array1.every(          
                (element_1) => {

                    if(element_2.start_date < element_1.start_date && element_1.start_date < element_2.end_date) return OVERLAP;
                    if(element_2.start_date < element_1.end_date && element_1.end_date < element_2.end_date) return OVERLAP;
                    
                     
>! if(element_2.start_date == element_1.start_date && element_1.start_date == element_2.end_date) return MATCH;
>! 
>! 
>! if(element_2.start_date > element_1.start_date && element_1.start_date > element_2.end_date) return ready;
>! if(element_2.start_date > element_1.end_date && element_1.end_date > element_2.end_date) return ready;
>!                 }
            )
        )
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, the first if is just comparing if the time is the same, the second if statement is a condition when any of the first array date is within range of the second array or if any of the dates on the second array is within the range of the current selected element of the first array, the last if is a condition when the first date is outside the range of second date:

```js
let array1 = [{
    start_date: "2022-12-01",
    end_date: "2022-12-07",
  },
  {
    start_date: "2022-12-04",
    end_date: "2022-12-10",
  },

  {
    start_date: "2022-12-8",
    end_date: "2022-12-14",
  },
  {
    start_date: "2022-12-11",
    end_date: "2022-12-17",
  },
  {
    start_date: "2022-12-15",
    end_date: "2022-12-21",
  },

  {
    start_date: "2022-12-18",
    end_date: "2022-12-24",
  },

  {
    start_date: "2022-12-22",
    end_date: "2022-12-28",
  },
  {
    start_date: "2022-12-25",
    end_date: "2022-12-31",
  },
  {
    start_date: "2022-12-18",
    end_date: "2022-12-31",
  },
];

let array2 = [{
  start_date: "2022-12-18",
  end_date: "2022-12-31"
}];

function compareTwoArrayOfObjects(array1, array2) {
  const start2 = new Date(array2[0].start_date);
  const end2 = new Date(array2[0].end_date);

  return array1.map(elm_arr1 => {
    const start1 = new Date(elm_arr1.start_date);
    const end1 = new Date(elm_arr1.end_date);
    let status;

    if (start1.getTime() === start2.getTime() && end1.getTime() === end2.getTime()) {
      status = "match";
    } else if ((start1 > start2 && start1 < end2) || (end1 > start2 && end1 < end2) || (start2 > start1 && start2 < end1) || (end2 > start1 && end2 < end1)) {
      status = "overlap";
    } else if ((start1 < start2 && end1 < start2) || (start1 > end2 && end1 > end2)) {
      status = "ready";
    }
    return {
      ...elm_arr1,
      status,
    };
  });
}

const result = compareTwoArrayOfObjects(array1, array2);

console.log(result);
```

Assertion:

```js
let array1 = [{
    start_date: "2022-12-01",
    end_date: "2022-12-07",
  },
  {
    start_date: "2022-12-04",
    end_date: "2022-12-10",
  },

  {
    start_date: "2022-12-8",
    end_date: "2022-12-14",
  },
  {
    start_date: "2022-12-11",
    end_date: "2022-12-17",
  },
  {
    start_date: "2022-12-15",
    end_date: "2022-12-21",
  },

  {
    start_date: "2022-12-18",
    end_date: "2022-12-24",
  },

  {
    start_date: "2022-12-22",
    end_date: "2022-12-28",
  },
  {
    start_date: "2022-12-25",
    end_date: "2022-12-31",
  },
  {
    start_date: "2022-12-18",
    end_date: "2022-12-31",
  },
];

let array2 = [{
  start_date: "2022-12-18",
  end_date: "2022-12-31"
}];

function compareTwoArrayOfObjects(array1, array2) {
  const start2 = new Date(array2[0].start_date);
  const end2 = new Date(array2[0].end_date);

  return array1.map(elm_arr1 => {
    const start1 = new Date(elm_arr1.start_date);
    const end1 = new Date(elm_arr1.end_date);
    let status;

    if (start1.getTime() === start2.getTime() && end1.getTime() === end2.getTime()) {
      status = "match";
    } else if ((start1 > start2 && start1 < end2) || (end1 > start2 && end1 < end2) || (start2 > start1 && start2 < end1) || (end2 > start1 && end2 < end1)) {
      status = "overlap";
    } else if ((start1 < start2 && end1 < start2) || (start1 > end2 && end1 > end2)) {
      status = "ready";
    }
    return {
      ...elm_arr1,
      status,
    };
  });
}

const result = compareTwoArrayOfObjects(array1, array2);

console.log(result);

/*-- assertion --*/

let array_assert1 = [{
    "start_date": "2022-12-01",
    "end_date": "2022-12-07",
    "status": "ready"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-04",
    "end_date": "2022-12-10",
    "status": "ready"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-8",
    "end_date": "2022-12-14",
    "status": "ready"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-11",
    "end_date": "2022-12-17",
    "status": "ready"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-15",
    "end_date": "2022-12-21",
    "status": "overlap"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-18",
    "end_date": "2022-12-24",
    "status": "overlap"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-22",
    "end_date": "2022-12-28",
    "status": "overlap"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-25",
    "end_date": "2022-12-31",
    "status": "overlap"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-18",
    "end_date": "2022-12-31",
    "status": "match"
  }
];

let array_assert2 = [{
    "start_date": "2022-12-01",
    "end_date": "2022-12-07",
    "status": "ready"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-04",
    "end_date": "2022-12-10",
    "status": "overlap"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-8",
    "end_date": "2022-12-14",
    "status": "ready"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-11",
    "end_date": "2022-12-17",
    "status": "match"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-15",
    "end_date": "2022-12-21",
    "status": "overlap"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-18",
    "end_date": "2022-12-24",
    "status": "overlap"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-22",
    "end_date": "2022-12-28",
    "status": "overlap"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-25",
    "end_date": "2022-12-31",
    "status": "overlap"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2022-12-18",
    "end_date": "2022-12-31",
    "status": "match"
  }
];

const assertion1 = result.every((res, idx) => res.status === array_assert1[idx].status);

const assertion2 = result.every((res, idx) => res.status === array_assert2[idx].status);

console.log("resulting array is valid for assertion 1?", assertion1);
console.log("resulting array is valid for assertion 2?", assertion2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! much appreciated,  I see that you have declared status variable.and To validate if the status overlap/match/ready,i would like to assert that array 1 has the valid status (overlap/match/ready,) Can i use assert library to achieve this?

Comment: @Banu in that case you should make a new question, but to answer that, well of course you can use any kinds of assert library for that. Btw please accept the answer if it does answer your question

Comment: Can you please help me with an example when you say to make a new question?

Comment: @Banu I have updated my answer here, hopefully it helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74988462/compare-two-array-of-objects-to-validate-if-the-date-is-within-the-range --> Can you please take a look at it where i have a bit different scenario to handle? and help me with the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Can you advise if i can use javascript assert library this way to validate if array 1 has the status that is expected within if loop like below.                                                                  if (start1.getTime() === start2.getTime() && end1.getTime() === end2.getTime()) {
      status = "match";  assert(elm_arr1.status, match);
    }